# Javascript, frames, onclick event

Tags: javascript, events, iframe, frames

I am currently creating tool which will help us to automate our site. Currently our page is without frames, but tool should be able to handle them in case they will be added.

My problem is that I am saving xpath and other attributes of element and then using this information I can execute this saved test. So for example I have onclick event, which save all of these information about target. But how to get frame location of this element in JS and then if I will have this info, how to loop through all frames on page and then select document in this frame?

Comment: Why to iterate all frames, you can get the references directly from an element: `[document =] e.target.ownerDocument; [window =] e.target.ownerDocument.window;`.

Comment: Whoops, `[window =] e.target.ownerDocument.defaultView;`.

Comment: Ok, this how I can get the frame, but when I have this information how to select this frame ? Something like looping throuht all frames and select correct one ? Or?

Comment: What you mean with "select this frame"? You don't have to "select" anything, you already have the references. If you mean the `(i)frame` element on a parent page, you can get it from `window.frameElement` (`window` here is a window got from `e.target.ownerDocument.defaultView`). If you need a more detailed answer, please show an example of how you would use the saved data.

Comment: By "saving" I have understood you're storing data in a JS variable, please correct me if I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: Ok, lets say I have two frames, frame1 and frame2. On click action I will save element information like xpath tag etc and frame. This is saved to XML and I can acces properties(strings) of the element and also I hope some information about frames. Now during execution of saved test I need to distinguish which frame I need to select, so in our case frame1 or frame2.   If I can select correct frame, then I can get document and then I can perform click action on element, fe by xpath. Is it more clear now ?